# Incorporating alteration in tables. lightswitch

Tags: lightswitch-2013

I have created my application completely.

But now one of my table has to add one more filed in database.

Now my table in the database is altered for adding the new field

How should I make changes in LS serverProject and views to see the newly added field.

Lightswitch2013/HtmlClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server project, open up your Data Sources folder. Right click your datasource (your database) and then left click Update Datasource. From there you should be able to select any new columns you've added. (Note: I think in 2013 you can select the columns. I'm on 2015 now and you just select the tables and it will update all the columns.)